# R: merge columns with same name by take average of their values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have some problem processing data.

Say I have a data.frame:

```
ind   a   b   b   c   c   c   d
1   0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.9
2   0.2 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.7 0.4
...
```

So I want after processing, the columns with the same name will be merged and take the average value of them.
The above data.frame will be :

```
ind   a   b   c   d
1   0.1 0.2 0.5 0.9
2   0.2 0.5 0.7 0.4
...
```

Thanks for your reading and help!!

Comment: Is it a matrix, like the question says, or a matrix, like the tag does?

Comment: Please share your data with `dput()` so that it is reproducible. `dput(head(your_data, 4))` should be sufficient. That way we'll know if it's a `matrix` or a `data.frame`, if there are any other irregularities, and we'll be able to copy/paste the code into our R sessions.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, the data type is data.frame which is directly retrieved from  read.table()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to compute the sets of column indexes that each correspond to a single column name, and then run [`rowMeans()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html) once on each set.

We can use [`split()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html) on [`colnames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html) to compute the sets of column indexes as a list.

For a matrix:

```
sapply(split(seq_len(ncol(m)),colnames(m)),function(cis) rowMeans(m[,cis,drop=F]));
##        a   b   c   d ind
## [1,] 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.9   1
## [2,] 0.2 0.5 0.7 0.4   2
```

For a data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(split(seq_len(ncol(df)),colnames(df)),function(cis) rowMeans(df[cis])));
##     a   b   c   d ind
## 1 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.9   1
## 2 0.2 0.5 0.7 0.4   2
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ind=c(1L,2L),a=c(0.1,0.2),b=c(0.2,0.4),b=c(0.2,0.6),c=c(0.3,0.6),c=c(0.5,0.8
),c=c(0.7,0.7),d=c(0.9,0.4),check.names=F);
m <- as.matrix(df);
```